# CanCanCan :read block not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancancan

I'm trying to put a very simple authorization on my `Property` class in Rails 5. I've added the `can :read` condition to `ability.rb` and used `load_and_authorize_resource` in my controller and I can't even get it to hit the pry, let alone authorize the `:show` action. Am I missing something obvious?

```
# ability.rb

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    can :read, Property do |property|
      binding.pry
      PropertyUser.find_by(property_id: property.id, user_id: user.id)
    end
  end
end




# properties_controller.rb

class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  skip_authorize_resource :only => [:new, :create]

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def set_property
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, it is trying to authorize the controller action name, therefore  you would not try to authorize :read, but :show, maybe that's what's going on.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, I actually already tried this and it didn't fix the problem

Comment: There's a few more things, I think you can get rid of `set_property`, Cancancan should do that for you either way.

Comment: If you need it because of the custom name you can use https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#custom-class

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I didn't know that. Still no luck in authorizing the show page though.

Comment: I'm not super sure what `authorize` does under the hood, but I suspect that it calls `current_user.can?(:show, property)` which means that you'd need to delegate `can?` and `cannot?` to the Ability object for the current user

Comment: Will show some sample code in an answer

Comment: maybe try replacing `PropertyUser.find_by(property_id: property.id, user_id: user.id)` with `PropertyUser.find_by(property_id: property.id, user_id: user.id).exists?`

Answer (score 0):

instead of `load_and_authorize_resource`, you can just use `authorize_resource` and then check. I don't think we need `delegate` here because the `CanCanCan` will do that automatically. It will automatically add these methods to `User` model.

Comment: Good to know but it didn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure you have Property objects in your database.

Comment: Try debugging as shown [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Debugging-Abilities)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to have this code in your `user.rb`

```
delegate :can?, :cannot?, to: :ability

def ability
  Ability.new(self)
end
```

Comment: Well I had other authorisations working previously so I don't think this is the problem. I gave it a try anyway and it didn't work.